# Windows 2003 Ntfs error Event 55 every 15 minutes

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-event-log, logging

I have Windows 2003 with four errors every 15 minutes in my EventLog.

`The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk     utility on the volume`

I ran chkdsk and no errors found. Windows  starts and seems to be working fine. I did not  install software before the errors started.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run check disk against all disks?  You would need to run it against each volume, such as chkdsk D: and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The data section of the event, formatted as WORDS, will usually give you an NTSTATUS value which might help you narrow down on what the problem is - although it will probably just tell you that you have a corrupt file - maybe going as far as to say a corrupt system file or corrupt eventlog file.

If you want to work out exactly which file or directory is corrupt, you can use Sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

Run Process Monitor (procmon) before the next expected occurrence of the file corrupt error being logged to the system log. Protip: Run procmon with the */noconnect* switch to prevent it from instantly logging everything.

Turn off registry and network monitoring, and just leave the file monitoring turned on. Add a filter on the result of "FILE CORRUPT".

[image: Process Monitor Filter]

When the corruption occurs again, you should see some information about which file is corrupt, and which process was accessing it. An example of that information can be [seen here](http://deusexmachina.uk/evdoco/event.php?event=20) (I don't have a corrupt file to hand that I can repeat this on to screenshot).

NB: This question was asked about Windows Server 2003. If you attempt to do this on Windows 2008 or later, make sure that you launch

```
procmon.exe /noconnect
```

from an elevated command prompt.